# Execute twiml bin from external call handler

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a self hosted voice ivr - it uses the Twilio php sdk.

Is there a way to trigger a twiml bin based on a gather input?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would set the action URL of your Gather verb to the URL of your TwiML Bin.